# How to make a chrome.storage.local variable increase 1 in each loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
function inc()
{
    chrome.storage.local.get("value",function(item){
        chrome.storage.local.set({"value":item["value"]+1},function(){});
    });
}
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    inc();
}
```

This is a chrome extension's inject.js,and "value" is a number,when I refreshed the page,it only increase one.So I try to add a alert(); statement above the inc statement,the "value" increase 5,is there another way to increase 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this:

```
function inc()
{
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(item) {
        chrome.storage.local.set({'value' : (item.value + 1)},function(){});
    });
}

for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    inc();
}
```